# innerText vs outerText

Tags: html, dom, innertext

After searching through web i understood the difference between innerHTML and outerHTML.

However i am having hard time understanding the difference between innerText and outerText.
Both appear almost same to me.

Can anyone help me understand this with a nice illustration ?

Thank You !

Comment: First Google result described it pretty well: `outerText`: Enables you to change all the element’s text, *including* the start and end tags.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

`innerText` changes only text within HTML tags, e.g.

```
<div>
  <p>Change Me</p>
</div>

p.innerText = "Changed!"
```

**Becomes**

```
<div>
  <p>Changed!</p>
</div>
```

Whereas `outerText`:

```
<div>
  <p>Change Me</p>
</div>

p.outerText = "Changed!"
```

**Becomes**

```
<div>
   Changed!
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent answer, short and sweet.

Answer (score 19):

Basically,
**innerText**: what's between the tags of the element.
**outerText**: content of the element, *including* the tags.

Comment: Just as a side note: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/outerText `This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.`