# VBS to get an Element from a web page is not working properly

Tags: html, vbscript

I want to get the value '24' in my VBS, which is set in the div with id 'test'. My HTML is:

```html
<html><body>
Welcome <br /> Value: = <div id="test">24</div> 
<br> Name: <p id="name">Someone</p><br>
</body></html>
```

And my VBS is:

```vb
on error resume next
set ie=createobject("internetExplorer.Application")

ie.navigate "http://localhost/h/getid.html"
ie.visible = false
wscript.sleep 2000

dim val
set val =ie.document.getElementsById("test").item(1).value
wscript.echo "value is= "& val
```

But the output does not show the value "24", it is just echoing

> value is=

How can I get that value?

Answer (score 2):

You should not ask a question here that concerns a script with an active "On Error
Resume Next". That is a waste of everybody's time. By *not* hiding errors/Pay attention to
error messages, you can solve the problem(s) on your own (most of the time).

Delete/Deactive the OERN and you get

```
set val =ie.document.getElementsById("test").item(1).value
==>
... runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'ie.document.getElementsById'
```

Even if you don't recognize the typo, a google search for "html dom getelementsbyid"
will re-route you to "Ergebnisse für [i.e. results for] html dom getelementbyid".
Follow one of the first links ([e.g.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) to refresh you knowledge about that method.

That way the next error:

```
set val =ie.document.getElementById("test").item(1).value
==>
... runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'ie.document.getElementById(...).item'
```

won't surprise you. An element isn't a collection of items/elements. [BTW: You shouldn't
post answers here without at least basic tests].

The next version

```
set val =ie.document.getElementById("test").value
```

should raise a red alert: An assignment with Set, but a right value that wants to be a
property of an object. That is blantantly wrong. So try:

```
set elm =ie.document.getElementById("test")  ' at least a decent assignment
val = elm.value
==>
... runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'elm.value'
```

A google query like "html dom div text" will point you to "[innerText](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5284240)"
and its features: [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18481435)

At last:

```
set elm =ie.document.getElementById("test")  ' at least a decent assignment
val = elm.innerText
```

success!

```
cscript 23971918.vbs
value is= 24
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need change `getElementsById` with `getElementById`.

Answer (score 0):

Someone mentioned you should change the getElementsById to getElementById (no 's'),  but I also think you should lose the .item(1) in this line: 
set val =ie.document.getElementsById("test").item(1).value

If I'm remembering correctly, using .item(#) would be appropriate if your object was a collection, like something returned by using .getElementsByTagName but .getElementById should only return one item.

Hope that helps!